# Laravel blade file can't view

Tags: laravel-5.8

I created CustomerController in Http, later, I fixed-route get customers, but getting an error in a single action Controller.

I tried to show off CustomerController view for displaying customers logged in page

[image: coding error image]

**Here is my error message:**

Use of undefined constant view - assumed 'view' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: Please don't post images, post your code and errors as text.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to access the old ways to render blade file look at this :-

```
 return View::make('customers.index', $customersList);
```

To use **view()** method

```
return view('admin.pages.customers.index',compact('someVaiable'));

OR

// You can define constant for your controller get methods

private $layout;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->layout = 'admin.pages.customers.';
}

public function index(){
    return view($this->layout.'index');
}
```

Take a look a this for **Single Action Controllers** example

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#single-action-controllers

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of the view method in the controller should be the name of the view.

> Routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'CustomerController');
```

> app/Http/Controllers/CustomerController.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        return view('customers');
    }
}
```

> resources/views/customers.blade.php

```
<h1>Customers</h1>
```

Comment: What part doesn't work, does it show customers? or another error @SolaimanHossain

Comment: Did you get it working or are there some other issues? @SolaimanHossain

Comment: I didn't fix the problem yet. Could you solve the problem please? @MaartenDev

Comment: I have solved this problem by using this  public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        return view('customers');
    }